# Jasmine spec timed out resetting the webdriver control flow

Tags: javascript, selenium, webdriver, protractor

I'm super stumped now with this error I keep getting back from Protractor when running test suites with Internet Explorer.

These tests are passing just fine in Chrome but when it comes to IE it seems to be handling timeouts a little differently.

Below is a bit of the protractor config file:

```
exports.config = {
  framework: 'jasmine2',
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    showColors: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: 120000
  },
  allScriptsTimeout: 120000,
  getPageTimeout: 120000,
  chromeDriver: null, //location of chromedriver and firefox binaries if null will attempt to find using PATH
  firefoxPath: null,
  params: {
    username: user@user.com',
    underTestUrl: 'localhost'
  },
  capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'internet explorer',
    'ie.ensureCleanSession': 'true'
  },
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:5000',
  jvmArgs: ['-Dwebdriver.ie.driver=IEDriverServer3.4.0.exe']
}
```

This question has been asked a few times & I have literally been over every fix even down to using the 32 bit version of IE Driver

Comment: Have you stumbled across this post http://elgalu.github.io/2014/run-protractor-against-internet-explorer-vm/ ?  It was a huge help to me setting up Protractor on IE (specifically step 4, with all the IE configuration options).  You can ignore the steps about setting up virtual box etc if you don't need it.

Comment: @Gunderson Thank you for the link but I have actually done these steps before hand. There were a few options on there which I had not done but they haven't made any difference. I believe the issue lies within Jasmines timeouts

Comment: where are the code that you used? are you using browser.sleep?